# list elements in a set resulting in error

Tags: python, list, set

I have the following code:

```
 d1=set()
 d2=set()
 d1={[12,1]}  
print(d1 & d2)
```

error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

What does this mean?
Cant the set contain a list element?
How do we rectify?

Thanks,
Sonia

Comment: @DhavalTaunk, no, you're not right.

Comment: @DhavalTaunk, `{ }` declarres set as well as dict, you wrote opposit.

Comment: @DhavalTaunk: Braces are used for set literals too. [Have an example.](https://ideone.com/KDkT3I) The existing use for dict literals means you can't use braces for an empty set, but other than that, there's no conflict.

Comment: `set([12, 1])` would create a set whose elements are `12` and `1`, not a set with a list as an element. A list cannot be an element of a set.